# Cant deploy a release version with developer profile

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, provisioning

I cant make a release build which is signed with my developer profile. I duplicated the release config and changed the signing cert to my developer profile but when it builds it signs with the App Store cert.

So I get the the standard dialog telling me that the app cant be installed on the device because it doesn't have the necessary profile (App Store Profile).

Id like to able to test the release builds before sending out for review but im wondering why I cant and if this is an Xcode bug. Im using XCode 3.2.5 . So far I have got away with just testing the debug builds but I'm sure I am going to get bitten on the a** some time.

Comment: What are the specific outputs of Xcode regarding the certificates?

Comment: Lost the verbose logging in Xcode but clarified in edit. I just get a standard dialog telling me the device doesnt have the neccessary profile (App Store). I might just have a go at cloning debug and cranking up the optimisation.

Comment: Some XCode wierdness. Clone the Debug config and crank up the optimisation and it works.

Comment: In these cases I usually open .xcodeproj file inside the .xcodeproject bundle and fix the wrong references by hand.

Comment: Make sure you are changing your code signing settings on the target, and not on the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Distribution Ad Hoc provisioning profile (as opposed to a Development Ad Hoc profile).  This way, you can test that code signing with your Distribution certificate works, and install on your device.

Then, simply duplicate the build configuration you just created, and set to your App Store Provisioning Profile, and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You can't install an app signed with your Distribution profile on your device.

What you should do is to test your Release build using your Developer profile, play with optimizations, etc., then make an **exact** copy of your Release Build Settings for the Distribution build, and just change the codesigning certificate only.  Thus the binaries should then be identical to those you've tested; only the codesigning stuff inside the app bundle should differ.

Comment: I know i cant install an app signed with the distribution profile. The question was why was a release build which has the dev profile cert selected in the config still being signed with the distribution cert.

Comment: Did you check your Target's Build Setting's for your Release build (and not some other build)?